# Dissalow users to chose the same day for date range, react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, date-range, react-datepicker

I have a date range using `react-datepicker` (with `selectsRange`)

My code snippet looks like:

```
      <DatePicker
        onChange={handleChange}
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        selectsRange
        popperPlacement="bottom-start"
        disabledKeyboardNavigation
        customInput={
          <DateRangeCustomInput
            isOpen={isOpen}
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
          />
        }
        onCalendarClose={handleCalendarClose}
        onCalendarOpen={handleCalendarOpen}
        maxDate={maxDate}
        excludeDates={excludedDates}
      />
```

My task is to disallow users to choose the same day for time range. For example, it's impossible to choose April 1 for the start and for the end of the range. I mean user shouldn't be able to click on the same day.

I was trying to use `minDate` and `excludeDates` for that reason, but they change the styles of excluded dates and when user hovers on the end date, there are blank days in the range.

[image]